# Vue CLI - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm beginner in VueJS and hoping for your help.

I'm trying to create Weather forecast app based on `OpenWeatherMap API`.

The concept is such that:

1. Enter some location to input on homepage and click to search button. (in my code it's a component `Search.vue`)
2. Redirecting to another page and show results - current weather and forecast for next 6 days. (component `Weather.vue`)

I created function with two consistent fetch calls. First fetch taking entered input `query` and return needed data from `Current Weather Data API`. After that, function run second fetch to `One Call API` based on `latitude` `longitude` from first fetch.

Everything is working and showing fine, but i don't undestand why i have an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')` in console:
[image]
[image]

**Сan someone know how to fix this error?**

My `Search.vue` (homepage) component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="search-col col">
            <div class="search-box">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="search-bar" 
                    placeholder="Location" 
                    v-model="query">
                <router-link :to="{name: 'DetailedWeather', params: { query: query }}" class="btn-search">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

My `Weather.vue` (weather results showing page) component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row" v-if="typeof weather.main != 'undefined'">
        <div class="weather-col col">
            <div class="weather-app">
                <div class="weather-box">
                    <div class="weather-top-info">
                        <div class="clouds-level"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cloud"></i></span> {{ weather.clouds.all }}%</div>
                        <div class="humidity"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-tint"></i></span> {{ weather.main.humidity }}%</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weather-main-info">
                        <div class="temp-box">
                            <div class="temp-main">{{ Math.round(weather.main.temp) }}</div>
                            <div class="temp-inner-box">
                                <div class="temp-sign">°C</div>
                                <div class="temp-max"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up"></i></span> {{ Math.round(weather.main.temp_max) }}°</div>
                                <div class="temp-min"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span> {{ Math.round(weather.main.temp_min) }}°</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="weather-desc">{{ weather.weather[0].description }}</div>
                        <div class="weather-icon">
                            <img :src="'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/'+ weather.weather[0].icon +'@4x.png'">  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weather-extra-info">
                        <div>Feels like: <span>{{ Math.round(weather.main.feels_like) }}°C</span></div>
                        <div>Sunrise: <span>{{ weather.sys.sunrise }}</span></div>
                        <div>Sunset: <span>{{ weather.sys.sunset }}</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="forecast-col col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="forecast-item-col col"  v-for="day in forecastDays" :key="day">
                    <div class="forecast-box">
                        <div class="forecast-date">{{ forecast.daily[day].dt }}</div>
                        <div class="forecast-temp">{{ Math.round(forecast.daily[day].temp.day) }}°C</div>
                        <div class="forecast-icon"><img :src="'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/'+ forecast.daily[day].weather[0].icon +'@2x.png'"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="actions-col col">
            <router-link :to="{name: 'Search'}" class="btn btn-default">
                Back to search
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Weather',
        props: ['query'], //getting from homepage
        data() {
            return {
                api_key:'b7fe640e9a244244a6f806f3a6cbf5fc',
                url_base:'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
                forecastDays: 6,
                weather: {},
                forecast: {}
                
            }
        },
    methods: {
        fetchWeather(){
            // first call
            fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&appid=${this.api_key}`)
            .then(response =>{ return response.json() }).then(this.setResults);
        },
        setResults(results){
          this.weather = results;

          // consistent second call
          fetch(`${this.url_base}onecall?lat=${results.coord.lat}&lon=${results.coord.lon}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&units=metric&appid=${this.api_key}`)
          .then(data =>{ return data.json() }).then(this.setForecast);
        },
    
        setForecast(results){
            this.forecast = results
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchWeather();
    }
</script>
```

My `router/index.js` file:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Search from '../components/Search.vue'
import Weather from '../components/Weather.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Search',
    component: Search
  },
  {
    path: '/detailed-weather',
    name: 'DetailedWeather',
    component: Weather,
    props: true
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: is `setForecast` defined somewhere ? Can you show what's on our component Weather.vue line 57 ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot adding that, my mistake :D It's a simple method to rewriting results for `forecast` data after second fetch. Added in my code in `methods`

Comment: what's the value of forecast?

Comment: it'a json, example:
`{{ forecast.daily[0] }}`
`{ "dt": 1636365600, "sunrise": 1636350992, "sunset": 1636384485, "moonrise": 1636367940, "moonset": 1636393920, "moon_phase": 0.14, "temp": { "day": 7.98, "min": 5.56, "max": 8.38, "night": 7.57, "eve": 8.21, "morn": 5.82 }, "feels_like": { "day": 4.71, "night": 4.56, "eve": 5.61, "morn": 2.21 }, "pressure": 1019, "humidity": 81, "dew_point": 4.84, "wind_speed": 6.54, "wind_deg": 268, "wind_gust": 12.3, "weather": [ { "id": 500, "main": "Rain", "description": "light rain", "icon": "10d" } ], "clouds": 97, "pop": 0.79, "rain": 2.2, "uvi": 0.37 }`

Answer (score 0):

From what I guess (given the code and the error), there might be an issue with the objects you are receiving from the API.

The error message suggests you are trying to read something from an array at a specific index that is undefined.

The only occurrence in your code that could cause this error is from the template, where you are reading, for example:

```
{{ forecast.daily[day].dt }}
{{ Math.round(forecast.daily[day].temp.day) }}
```

I can't tell exactly which one is it, but try to double check the shape of the objects you are working with.

Comment: Sry but i can't undestand which solving you propose :/
`{{ forecast.daily[day].dt }}` successfully returned: `1636365600`.
Also `{{ Math.round(forecast.daily[day].temp.day) }}` returned: `8`. Error is same. Can you show me in my code what can i need to do?